# Can such matrices have repeated eigenvalues with different eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider matrices of the following form:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & ... & a_{n-1} &a_n\\
1 & 0 & ... & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & ... & 0 & 0 \\
... & ... & ... & 0 & 0 \\
0 & ... & ... & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Can such matrices have a repeated eigenvalue $\lambda$ (i.e., the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda \geq 2$), with the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda$ = $\dim\{E_{\lambda}\} \geq 2.$

I tried some 2 by 2 cases but I did not find a counter example. Thanks a lot.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix as what you have there is, in essence, a companiion matrix. If the eigenvalues of a companion matrix are not distinct, then the matrix is not diagonalizable, i.e., does not have enough distinct eigenvectors to form a basis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall the following

> The rank nullity theorem :
> $$ \dim V = \dim \ker T + rank(T)$$
> where for $T : V \to V$ is a linear map and $\dim V = n.$

> The rank of $T$ is the number of linearly independent lines of the matrix $T$.

Consider the matrix $T = A- \lambda I$.

$$T=\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 - \lambda & a_2 & ... & a_{n-1} &a_n\\
1 & -\lambda & ... & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & ... & 0 & 0 \\
... & ... & ... & -\lambda & 0 \\
0 & ... & ... & 1 & -\lambda
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Notice the following

> If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then $\dim \ker T \geq 1$

> The lines $\{$line $2$, line $3, \dots,$ line $n \}$ of the matrix $T$ are linearly independent. Hence $rank(T) \geq (n-1)$

It follows that
$$ \dim \ker (A- \lambda I) = 1$$
whenever $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. That is, all the eigenvalues of $A$ have geometric multiplicity $1$.

The answer is therefore "No !"

Comment: Thanks a lot, very elegant proof.

Comment: @WilliamZheng Yes, I thought so too :)

Answer (score 0):

You already got a nice proof from Digitallis but I think it may be instructive to also directly give the generalized eigenvectors of that matrix. What you have is basically a companion matrix for the following (monic) polynomial:

$$p(x)=x^n-a_1x^{n-1}-a_2x^{n-2}-...-a_{n-1}x-a_n$$

This polynomial is also the characteristic polynomial of the matrix. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of the matrix it's also a root of the polynomial meaning:

$$p(\lambda)=\lambda^n-a_1\lambda^{n-1}-a_2x^{n-2}-...-a_{n-1}\lambda-a_n=0$$

Using this it's easy to verify that the following vector is that eigenvalue's corresponding eigenvector:

$$\vec{v_0}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda^{n-1} \\
\lambda^{n-2} \\
\vdots \\
\lambda \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

It should be easy to see that $(A-\lambda I)\vec{v_0}=\vec{0}$. The result for the top row comes from the polynomial identity for the root $\lambda$ and for the lower rows it's immediately clear. If the root is a double root the derivative of the polynomial at $x=\lambda$ is also $0$:

$$p\prime(\lambda)=n\lambda^{n-1}-(n-1)a_1\lambda^{n-2}-(n-2)a_2x^{n-3}-...-a_{n-1}=0$$
$$n\lambda^{n-1}=(n-1)a_1\lambda^{n-2}+(n-2)a_2x^{n-3}+...+a_{n-1}$$

Using this it should be easy to see that the following vector is a generalized eigenvector for the eigenvalue:

$$\vec{v_1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
(n-1)\lambda^{n-2} \\
(n-2)\lambda^{n-3} \\
\vdots \\
1 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Again, you can easily verify that $(A-\lambda I)\vec{v_1}=\vec{v_0}$. The result for the top row comes from the above polynomial identity and for the lower rows it's immediately clear. It follows that $\vec{v_1}$ is a generalized eigenvector (of rank 2) but not an eigenvector of $\lambda$ and thus the geometric multiplicity is $1$. If the polynomial has a root with a higher multiplicity, say $k$, then you can similarly find a Jordan chain of $k$ generalized eigenvectors.